# How to extract substrings for a normal string python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, substring

I am looking for a way to extract a part of a string (I think they are called substrings). I have looked for a solution, but haven't found one. Here is an example:
`

```
text = input('Insert Math Problem: ')
'''Insert substring recognition script here'''
if text contains('3') and text contains('4'):
    print('Contains three and four!')
else:
    print('Does not contain three and four.')`
```

For example if I typed in `What is 3 * 4`, how would I get just the `3 * 4` part? The type of substring I would like to have extracted is the operation and the two numbers surrounding it. I would also like it to be flexible in a way that it could find 3*4 or 3 times 4. My Python version is 3.6.4 and I am using a Mac.

Comment: Make the question more specific. What type of substrings need to be extracted? Does it involve numbers and mathematical operators like "3*4" or can it contain a mixture like "3 times 4"? Just to be clear there is no general solution for this kind of problems. For simple strings you can use specific regular expressions, for more complex problem you need more complex tools like lexer/parsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works the way you want to be. This extracts substring involving numbers and mathematical operators (+, /, *, -)  out of a text using [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module.

```
import re 
text = 'foo 3 * 4 - 5 / 6 + 7 foo' 
regex = r'\d+|[+/*-]'   
elem = re.findall(regex, text) 
result = ' '.join(i for i in elem)
print(result)
```

Outputs:

```
3 * 4 - 5 / 6 + 7
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to accomplish this, one option is to  use the [re](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html) module to identify the first numerical digit (`\d`) and then capture the remainder (`*`) as the substring:

```
import re
substring = re.sub('^[^\d]*', '', text)

print substring
```

output:

```
3 * 4
```

Comment: Does this work for subtraction? I tried your answer but instead of the * after the [^\d], I put - for use with subtraction.

Comment: Also, how do you detect the substring in between words? For example, Foo 3 * 4 foo.

Comment: Yes this works for other inputs. you don't need to change symbols for it to work with subtraction. The `*` in the script is not multiplication but regex syntax for repeating characters in the substring. Run the script here: http://repl.it/@downshift/WeightyBustlingVelociraptor with different inputs `'What is 3 - 4'`, etc., and only the operation `3 - 4` portion is returned.

Comment: Maybe your goal is more specific and I misunderstood your question. My answer won't detect multiple parts of the string as in your example.  Check the comments and other answer and give us more details. Thanks for your feedback.